# git checkout master accidently aborted

Tags: git, tortoisegit

My Tortoise Git was checking out my master branch, when I hit the ESC key. I didn't realise the Toirtoise window had focus, so it stopped the checkout.

But my active branch is still not "master". Now when I try to checkout master again, it says "Aborting" after a few files, and then Tortoise says: git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1).

I tried removing the index.lock from the .git directory. This helped a bit: instead of Aborting immediately, it now checks out and overwrites a few files, and then aborts.

How can I fix my master branch, or force it to switch? I have a remote staging branch which I could use to pull the latest changes from. I could just start with a new git repository, but then I'd loose my other (local) branches.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try **git fsck**. (I would "man git-fsck" first.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the command line to see what's going on.

try executing `git checkout master` then comment here what the output is.